# Probable fatal error:No fonts found-while setting sheet.autoSizeColumn

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-poi

I am creating a program that writes information to an excel file using the apache poi..every thing working fine until i used

```
 sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
```

after adding this code .i am getting  a exception
`java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found`.

i researched about this and found that  it is because of  absence of fonts.if i comment the  above code ,every thing works fine.my question is how the 
     `sheet.autoSizeColumn`  function  is related with font . and  also i need to install fonts,i am using  Ubuntu 12.04.2 , tomcat 7, and  java-6-openjdk-amd64
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you make sure that all the fonts you use are installed on your machine + available to the JVM?

Comment: @Gagravarr how can i make  fonts available to Jvm

Comment: That's a very different question, and should be asked as such! (Alex's answer explains why they need to be available for your use case, you just need to arrange it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of characters depends on which font is chosen. For instance, the width of the same phrase written with 10pt `Arial` and 10pt `Times New Roman` fonts is different. So, to calculate the width of the column apache-poi should know about the font you're using. Therefore, you should set the font for each cell you want to autosize. Here's an example:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setFontHeight(14.0);
//some additional font configuration
cellStyle.setFont(font);
//For each cell:
    cell.setStyle(cellStyle)
```

Notice that you need to create `cellStyle` just one time, and then apply it to every cell that should have this style.

Answer (score 0):

On centos with zulu jdk running below command fixed my issue.

```
yum install fontconfig -y
```